# getting error java: cannot find symbol symbol: method chrome() location: class Abstract.Abstract

Tags: desiredcapabilities

I have started building up my first Selenium-Java automation project. I am getting error because not able to find chrome in code line DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

```
try {
                Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
                mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", deviceName);
                Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
                //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/user/path");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.get(baseURL);
                MDC.put("BrowserName", "Responsive");
                MDC.put("DeviceName", deviceName);
                extent = new ExtentReports(
                        System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/ExtentReport.html", true);
                //extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "teststaf.mi4biz.net")
                extent.addSystemInfo("Host Name", "https://testsanem.mi4biztest.net/");
                       
                extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\extent-config.xml"));
                inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("responsiveElement.properties");
```

Tries to find my method in here;

```
public class DesiredCapabilities extends MutableCapabilities {

  public DesiredCapabilities(String browser, String version, Platform platform) {
    setCapability(BROWSER_NAME, browser);
    setCapability(BROWSER_VERSION, version);
    setCapability(PLATFORM_NAME, platform);
  }

  public DesiredCapabilities() {
    // no-arg constructor
  }

  public DesiredCapabilities(Map<String, ?> rawMap) {
    if (rawMap == null) {
      return;
    }

    rawMap.forEach(this::setCapability);
  }

  public DesiredCapabilities(Capabilities other) {
    merge(other);
  }

  public DesiredCapabilities(Capabilities... others) {
    for (Capabilities caps : others) {
      merge(caps);
    }
  }

  public void setBrowserName(String browserName) {
    setCapability(BROWSER_NAME, browserName);
  }

  public void setVersion(String version) {
    setCapability(BROWSER_VERSION, version);
  }

  public void setPlatform(Platform platform) {
    setCapability(PLATFORM_NAME, platform);
  }

  public boolean acceptInsecureCerts() {
    if (getCapability(ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS) != null) {
      Object raw = getCapability(ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS);
      if (raw instanceof String) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean((String) raw);
      } else if (raw instanceof Boolean) {
        return (Boolean) raw;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public void setAcceptInsecureCerts(boolean acceptInsecureCerts) {
    setCapability(ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, acceptInsecureCerts);
  }
```

I tried to change method chrome(), but it didn't worked. Should I edit DesiredCapabilities class.
I was expecting to rename the method with something valuable and able to find symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code block like below and it is fixed. Thank you.

```
Map<String, String> mobileEmulation = new HashMap<String, String>();
            mobileEmulation.put("deviceName", deviceName);
            Map<String, Object> chromeOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromeOptions.put("mobileEmulation", mobileEmulation);
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
            capabilities.setCapability("chromeVersion", "118.0");

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/path");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(baseURL);
            MDC.put("BrowserName", "Responsive");
            MDC.put("DeviceName", deviceName);
            extent = new ExtentReports(
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/ExtentReport.html", true);
            extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\extent-config.xml"));
            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("responsiveElement.properties");
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?